# Django reset password url in email only works if copy and paste it, not click on it

Tags: django

When I request a password reset with the built in django machinery, it will generate a URL in the email like this:

```
https://example/accounts/reset/MTA/atspc3-7c45df8a600243fde3dfb60c44873f15/
```

In gmail if I go show URL, the text is indentical since it is being generated as a plain/text email. If I click the link in gmail, or outlook then it goes to (maybe after a redirect, I can't tell since its so fast):

```
https://example.com/accounts/reset/MTA/set-password/
```

And it says

```
Password reset unsuccessful
The password reset link was invalid, possibly because it has already been used. Please request a new password reset.
```

However if I copy and paste the URL into the browser, then it works. However no-one copies and paste the URL, they all click the link and say it does not work.
I don't get why clicking on the link does not work since it is correct?

I managed to add logging to Django's code, I added logging to:

```
contrib.auth.views -> PasswordResetConfirmView.dispatch (line 247)
```

As you can see from the following two logs, in both scenarios they are being called with exactly the same locals (I print locals()), however this view seems to set the token in the session, then redirect. however after the redirect, if one cicked the link in the email, the session cookie is gone, and hence it fails. I still don't understand why

### COPY and paste URL (Working)

```
------------------------------------------------------------
# First call to dispatch:
token: atspc3-7c45df8a600243fde3dfb60c44873f15
Entered dispatch {'self': <django.contrib.auth.views.PasswordResetConfirmView object at 0x7f20e63c2220>, 'args': (<WSGIRequest: GET '/accounts/reset/MTA/atspc3-7c45df8a600243fde3dfb60c44873f15/'>,), 'kwargs': {'uidb64': 'MTA', 'token': 'atspc3-7c45df8a600243fde3dfb60c44873f15'}, 'token': 'atspc3-7c45df8a600243fde3dfb60c44873f15', '__class__': <class 'django.contrib.auth.views.PasswordResetConfirmView'>}
user is not None
token is NOT reset
token atspc3-7c45df8a600243fde3dfb60c44873f15
Verfiy sessions token atszyc-e7c578496e3438f9dee367fcbebfabb1
redirect url /accounts/reset/MTA/set-password/
Djnago logging start
------------------------------------------------------------
# Second call to dispatch (after redirect):
token: set-password
Entered dispatch {'self': <django.contrib.auth.views.PasswordResetConfirmView object at 0x7f20e63c2220>, 'args': (<WSGIRequest: GET '/accounts/reset/MTA/set-password/'>,), 'kwargs': {'uidb64': 'MTA', 'token': 'set-password'}, 'token': 'set-password', '__class__': <class 'django.contrib.auth.views.PasswordResetConfirmView'>}
user is not None
token is self reset, session token: atspc3-7c45df8a600243fde3dfb60c44873f15
```

### CLICK link in email (Not working)

```
------------------------------------------------------------
# First call to dispatch:
token: atspc3-7c45df8a600243fde3dfb60c44873f15
Entered dispatch {'self': <django.contrib.auth.views.PasswordResetConfirmView object at 0x7f20d9a77190>, 'args': (<WSGIRequest: GET '/accounts/reset/MTA/atspc3-7c45df8a600243fde3dfb60c44873f15/'>,), 'kwargs': {'uidb64': 'MTA', 'token': 'atspc3-7c45df8a600243fde3dfb60c44873f15'}, 'token': 'atspc3-7c45df8a600243fde3dfb60c44873f15', '__class__': <class 'django.contrib.auth.views.PasswordResetConfirmView'>}
user is not None
token is NOT reset
token atspc3-7c45df8a600243fde3dfb60c44873f15
Verfiy sessions token atszyc-e7c578496e3438f9dee367fcbebfabb1
redirect url /accounts/reset/MTA/set-password/
------------------------------------------------------------
# Second call to dispatch (after redirect):
token: set-password
Entered dispatch {'self': <django.contrib.auth.views.PasswordResetConfirmView object at 0x7f20d9adde20>, 'args': (<WSGIRequest: GET '/accounts/reset/MTA/set-password/'>,), 'kwargs': {'uidb64': 'MTA', 'token': 'set-password'}, 'token': 'set-password', '__class__': <class 'django.contrib.auth.views.PasswordResetConfirmView'>}
user is not None
token is self reset, session token: None
```

Here are the log statements I added to `contrib.auth.views -> PasswordResetConfirmView.dispatch (line 247)` :

```py
@method_decorator(never_cache)
    def dispatch(self, *args, **kwargs):
        log_info('------------------------------------------------------------')
        token = kwargs['token']
        log_info('token:', token)
        log_info('Entered dispatch', str(locals()))
        assert 'uidb64' in kwargs and 'token' in kwargs

        self.validlink = False
        self.user = self.get_user(kwargs['uidb64'])

        if self.user is not None:
            token = kwargs['token']
            log_info('user is not None')
            if token == self.reset_url_token:
                session_token = self.request.session.get(INTERNAL_RESET_SESSION_TOKEN)
                log_info('token is self reset, session token:', session_token)
                if self.token_generator.check_token(self.user, session_token):
                    # If the token is valid, display the password reset form.
                    self.validlink = True
                    return super().dispatch(*args, **kwargs)
            else:
                log_info('token is NOT reset')
                if self.token_generator.check_token(self.user, token):
                    # Store the token in the session and redirect to the
                    # password reset form at a URL without the token. That
                    # avoids the possibility of leaking the token in the
                    # HTTP Referer header.
                    self.request.session[INTERNAL_RESET_SESSION_TOKEN] = token
                    log_info('token', token)
                    log_info('Verfiy sessions token', self.request.session[INTERNAL_RESET_SESSION_TOKEN])
                    redirect_url = self.request.path.replace(token, self.reset_url_token)
                    log_info('redirect url', redirect_url)
                    return HttpResponseRedirect(redirect_url)
                else:
                    log_info('failed token generator check')
```

Note, in both cases the request has the following attributes (I thought it might be a secure cookie issue):

```py
request.scheme: https
request.is_secure: True
request.full path /accounts/reset/MTA/set-password/
or
request.full path /accounts/reset/MTA/atspc3-7c45df8a600243fde3dfb60c44873f15/
```

Comment: Could you share you email template, urls.py and views?

Comment: @black, I am using the built in email template, urls, and views. I have not customised anything. It baffles I don't know what is not working. the link works, the link in the email is the same, clicking the link in the email does not work. I would fix the url but the url is correct already.

Comment: The situation is definitely unexpected so we need to see your code to find where the problem is.

Comment: @black, thanks for the follow up, unfortunately none of it is my code, but please see some of the logging I added to django's code.

Answer (score 1):

In the rare case someone else has this issue, I had in my settings file:

```
SESSION_COOKIE_SAMESITE = 'Strict'
```

One must change the cookie to persist from an outside domain (the email client) as follows:

```
SESSION_COOKIE_SAMESITE = 'Lax'  # default value
```

Refer to https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/settings/#session-cookie-samesite